# Is there a way to get just the substate name in AngularJS somehow?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using UI-Router in AngularJs to register states. I need to get the substate name in my controller for executing a specific task.

Is there a way to get just the substate name somehow ?

I know from "$state.current.name", I will get the full state name but just wanted to check whether there is a direct access to the substate name.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a default function for that but you could write one yourself like so:

```
function getSubstateName() {
    var stateArray =  $state.current.name.split('.');
    return stateArray[stateArray.length - 1];
}
```

Comment: Yea Martijn, I have a similar function written already. I just wanted to make sure that there is no other way to do it.